# Elixir Pattern Matching Explained

Tags: pattern-matching, elixir

I am new to elixir and came across pattern matching for the first time in a tutorial. I've scoured the internet for a good explanation and have found none. The claim everyone makes is: the single equal operator does not mean assignment. It means match. ok... then, for a new variable x, why does

```
x = 1
```

assign the value of 1 to x? If it was the match operator then shouldn't it throw an error because x is not defined and therefore does not "match" 1? The best I can come up with in terms of internal logic is the following:

1. if the item on the left is undefined. assign the value on the right
2. if the item on the left is defined, match with the item on the right

Is this correct? If it is, then why is the single equal sign not the assign-match operator rather than the match operator?

Comment: it is the "assign-match operator " in effect - read more here https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/pattern-matching.html#the-match-operator  the pin operator helps out when you want to fix the match.

Comment: That is the tutorial I cam from. A bit frustrating that elixir denies that the operator is in any way related to assignment. Sounds like the author was doing the coder's version of "trying to be cool": "It isn't assign!! It is Match!! Look: 1 = x. See? Match. Look how cool elixir is!!". Just don't read the fine print.

Comment: When matching, variables are "bound" to values -- binding is conceptually similar to assignment, but I think there are technical differences (?).  When you do `x = 1`, `x` matches the entire pattern and it captures the entire value, i.e. `1`.  The behavior is not different if the variable `x` has already been defined.  However, if you had done `1 = x`, then the value of `x` must be resolved in order to do the comparison, and the behavior (and error) will be different depending on whether `x` has been defined or not.

Comment: I am going under the assumption that binding is the same as assignment for lack of a better theory. You say "x matches the entire pattern and it captures the entire value". "Capturing" is not a term I am familiar with. Does it also mean "assign"? I would assume all of these concepts should be a part of an elixir tutorial, rather than the obscure, and concise "= means match".

Comment: @WreckFish When asking for assistance, a less adversarial tone may get you better results. The world doesn't owe you an explanation.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip fair enough.